# How to integrate Solana with Flutter for storing data on the blockchain?

Tags: solana-program, solana-cli, dapp, flutter

I'm a beginner who is working on a project that requires **flutter and solana.** I don't have any idea on how to proceed with this. **The basic task I need to do is: Store data that is coming from Flutter app on Solana Blockchain.** I wanted to know if this integration is possible, and how to go about doing it. Also it would be helpful if you can also suggest a better alternative that I can try with flutter considering my requirements mentioned above. Since there are very less resources available when it comes to flutter and solana integration, I would be grateful if you could help me out with this.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a small but solid discord community of Solana x Flutter developers where you can join and ask for advice and guidance: https://discord.gg/Pc8vT75Gb5

Flutter integration is still in it's infancy but the team doing it is dedicated and has full support from Solana labs.

I believe that your question might be too broad for a stack.exchange discussion so might be best to move it to discord there. I also don't believe that there is some solid documentation and examples that I can link to you. Even if I did link something, it might become deprecated in a month and be useless for any new people entering this discussion.

Good luck building on blazing edge technologies :)